# How can I properly configure nginx to work with NG Serve and Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, nginx

I've been trying to research Nginx to configure a proxy with Angular 5 ng serve on localhost:4200, however only come up with results for serving a project that's been built. The configuration I've found from this research "somewhat" works, but results in a white page that isn't loading any data:

```
dev:12 GET http://192.168.1.84/inline.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
dev:12 GET http://192.168.1.84/polyfills.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
dev:12 GET http://192.168.1.84/styles.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
dev:12 GET http://192.168.1.84/vendor.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
dev:12 GET http://192.168.1.84/main.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
```

It appears that it can't see the files served by ng serve, but is at least reaching the index.html page for the project. This is the configuration I am currently using:

```
location /dev {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_set_header Host localhost;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
}
```

What should I add to the /dev config?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, check your Angular app's `<base>` tag - it needs to match the app's new location.  So, for example, if you're hosting your app through nginx at `https://localhost/dev/`, your `<base>` tag will need to be:

```
<base href="/dev/">
```

You can find this tag in your app's `index.html`.

Second, nginx won't automatically proxy all the traffic that `ng serve` uses for live-reload functionality.  You can proxy this extra traffic by adding this to your `nginx.conf`:

```
location ^~ /sockjs-node/ {

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4200;

    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

This assumes that `ng serve` hosts your app on port 4200 (which is the default).

Comment: This worked for me, except that the location I need is location /ng-cli-ws - I got this from the network tab in my browser as the WS angular was trying to connect to, I hypothesise that the url may have changed between versions